# Как можно установить библиотеку Python не через pip

Tags: python

На работе пишет ошибку, связанную с прокси, поэтому было бы здорово, если бы можно было скачать файлы и закинуть куда-то, но я не знаю что да как. 
Нужно установить библиотеку PyPDF

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation/51646354

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch

Comment: Скачанные файлы через тот же самый pip и ставятся. В PyPI есть вкладка Download у всех проектов, можно взять и скачать, а потом установить эти файлы через pip install. https://pypi.org/project/pyPdf/#files

Comment: @andreymal Если я скачал файл pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz, то как мне поставить его через консоль? Что правильно написать? У меня windows

Comment: @andreymal я распаковал архив, а затем в консоль ввел setup.py install, но получил следующие ошибки
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimok.1575442127.png

Comment: @shadow1337 pypdf работает только на втором питоне, а вы пытаетесь поставить его на третьем. Или откатитесь на старый питон, или используйте другую библиотеку (например pypdf2)

Answer (score 1):

Для вашей библиотеки можно попробовать:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2@1.26.0
```

Если не взлетит, то есть более болезненый/менее рекомендуемый способ:

1. Скачать нужный пакет (https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/#files)
2. Распокавать его
3. В корне пакета запустить `python setup.py install`

Использование setup.py крайне не рекомендуется, т.к. потом "из коробки" удалить установленное не получится.